# flutter why can't I show my image from camera?

Tags: image, camera, flutter, show

I don't know why my code don't show the image from the camera..
I tried this code and the var isn't empty, but doesn't show the image in the container..
I don't get any error neither..
thanks for your help.

```
class _MyAppState extends State {
  File _imagen;
  Future getImagen() async {
    var imagen = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _imagen = imagen;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('picker'),
        ),

        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: _imagen == null
                ? new Text('no hay imagen')
                : new Image.file(_imagen),
          ),
        ),

        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: getImagen,
          child: Icon(Icons.camera),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use File dataType instead of var for _imagen  variable.

Comment: no, it still doesn't work.. 

Comment: I just find somthing.. It shows from gallery but not from camera folder, screenshoots is ok, and any other folder, but not camera folder. and if i change ImageSource.gallery for ImageSource.camera it doesn't work neither... any idea?? it's a real device

Comment: ImageSource.camera will prompt a camera to capture an Image, Imagesource.gallery will shows  you photos to select from already captured. So, if you capture image with ImageSource>camera then you see it as you are ble see with ImageSource.gallery

Comment: but i can't see the image captured from camera neither any image from the gallery from the camera folder (older pictures made with the device outside my app)

Comment: Try to downgrade package and use older version else file a issue in flutter github

Comment: i'm already usin image_picker: 0.4.12+1 instead of the last version for Fixing AndroidX crashes

Answer (score 4):

this issue is related to the image size. Adding this solved the issue for me.

```
await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 480, maxHeight: 600);
```

For further clarification, check out this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31374)

Answer (score 0):

change the image picker to latest 
`image_picker: ^0.6.0+10`